# SQLLite Update query Parameter not accepting System String value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqlite

I am having some issues with a parameterized SQL Lite query. I can't seem to get the SQL Lite Parameter to accept the String value

```
Using cmd As SQLiteCommand = pConn.CreateCommand()
    If tblLang = "en" Then
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [AT_Strings] SET [Data] = @tblData + 1 WHERE [RecordID] = @ID AND [language] = @tblLang1"
        Dim tblData As New SQLiteParameter("@tblData")
        Dim ID As New SQLiteParameter("@ID")
        Dim tblLang1 As New SQLiteParameter("@tblLang1")
        cmd.Parameters.Add(dataText)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ID)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(tblLang)
    Else
         cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [AT_Strings] SET [Data] = @dataText + 1 WHERE [RecordID] = @ID AND [language] = @tblLang1"
         Dim tblData As New SQLiteParameter("@dataText")
         Dim ID As New SQLiteParameter("@ID")
         Dim tblLang1 As New SQLiteParameter("@tblLang1")
         cmd.Parameters.Add(dataText)
         cmd.Parameters.Add(ID)
         cmd.Parameters.Add(tblLang)
    End If

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
 End Using
```

The error is as follows....

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter'.

Source Error: 

Line 283:  Dim ID As New SQLiteParameter("@ID")

Line 284:  Dim tblLang1 As New SQLiteParameter("@tblLang1")

ERROR on Line 285...

Line 285:  cmd.Parameters.Add(dataText)
```

Comment: Could you share a bit more of your code? Where is the `dataText` variable coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I solved this issue...

```
Dim SqlString As String 
SqlString = "UPDATE [AT_Strings] SET [Data] = @Data WHERE [ID] = @ID AND [Language] = @Language"  

Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(SqlString, pConn)    
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text     
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Data", dataText)    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", f4)    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Language", tblLang)     

    pConn.Open()    
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()    
    pConn.Close() 
End Using
```

Hope this helps someone else!!

Comment: what did you do in it? Can you explain?

Comment: @Volatil3 Instead of using cmd.Parameters.Add(..), you use cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ParameterName", yourGuid) which does an implicit conversion of your guid.